# How to skip last row using BULK INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to skip last row using `BULK INSERT`?

If not, is there a way I could pre-process text file using windows command line?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not inserting into a temporary table first? You can then omit the row you do not need while inserting to your target table.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx, CTRL+F, type LASTROW, enjoy

Comment: Using sql only or also some language like c#,php?

Comment: @Pred nice hint, but: If you do not know the actual count it is difficult to set the correct value... You'd have to do sort of row count (count line breaks?) first...

Comment: Why dont you bulk insert all rows into a table and then delete the last row from that table. Easier to manipulate data in SQL than using windows command line, IMO!

Comment: @Shnugo The question was if it is possible. It is possible with the LASTROW. The OP done zero research (at least, this is what I can tell based on the question). Yes, you have to know the row count to use last row. You have to know the order of the records to make any sense of the word "last". Should I post this link instead: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) ??

Comment: @Pred, Quite true...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is first open csv file as Stream for Appending and get last line. Then run bulk insert with LASTROW - 1

```
declare @fs int, @ole_response int
execute @ole_response = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @fs out
if @ole_response <> 0 RAISERROR('Error creating FileSystemObject.', 16, 1)

declare @fobj int
execute @ole_response = sp_OAMethod @fs, 'GetFile', @fobj out, @csv_file
if @ole_response <> 0 RAISERROR('Error GetFile.', 16, 1)

declare @fstream int
execute @ole_response = sp_OAMethod @fobj, 'OpenAsTextStream', @fstream out, 8 --ForAppending
if @ole_response <> 0 RAISERROR('Error OpenAsTextStream.', 16, 1)

declare @last_row int
execute @ole_response = sp_OAGetProperty @fstream, 'Line', @last_row output
if @ole_response <> 0 RAISERROR('Error reading property Line.', 16, 1)

execute @ole_response = sp_OAMethod @fstream, 'Close'
if @ole_response <> 0 RAISERROR('Error closing TextStream.', 16, 1)

execute sp_OADestroy @fs

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = N'
    BULK INSERT ##csv_data
    FROM ''' + @csv_file + N'''
    WITH (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
        ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0A'',
        CODEPAGE = ''65001'',
        LASTROW  = ' + cast(@last_row - 1 as nvarchar(max)) + '
    )
'


delete from ##csv_data
exec sp_executesql @sql
```